# Make dialogflow execute C# stored in my computer as a response to an Intent

Tags: javascript, c#, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I have an issue, I would like that Dialogflow executes C# code **in my computer** as a response to a determined Intent. I imagine the webhook feature offers a way of calling and executing locally a C# code. However, I have not found any guidance about this.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Fulfillment allows Dialogflow to call your own HTTPS endpoint in response to particular intents being matched; you can find the documentation [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

Your endpoint will receive a POST containing JSON with the same format as you'll see in the test console in Dialogflow's UI.

Answer (score 0):

use this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2/ it's a nuget specifically for dialogflow, and it's so easy to see the intents like this.

```
public GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse Post(GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookRequest obj)
    {
            string Location = string.Empty;

            switch (obj.QueryResult.Intent.DisplayName)
            {
                case "getstock":
                Location = obj.QueryResult.Parameters["Location"].ToString();
                break;
            }

            var response = new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse()
            {
                FulfillmentText = $"The stock at {Location} is valuing Rs. 31 Lakhs \n And consists of items such as slatwall, grid and new pillar. The detailed list of the same has been email to you",
                Source = "API.AI"
            };

            return response;
    }
```

from this answer: [dialogflow simple fulfillment webhook in c# not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856306/dialogflow-simple-fulfillment-webhook-in-c-sharp-not-working)